# python code creates file with tilde in title

Tags: python

The following code works as intended to create a new file (or files) using the file name (or names) in the directory.  However it also creates a file with a tilde in the title and a duplicate of the word2find. Here is an example result
 ~$17 Q3 Xcel retire retire.txt
 I don't understand why this is happening. Any explanations will be appreciated.   Cheers, BobS

```
import os, os.path,re, pprint,sys, nltk
sourcedir = 'C:/Users/Public/EnvDef/Proj/1 ErnCls/2 IOUErnClsQrtr/2017 Q3/23a Xcel'
os.chdir (sourcedir)
cwd = os.getcwd()
print ('New Current Working Directory     %s' % cwd)
for dirPath, subdirNames, fileList in os.walk(cwd):
    for filename in fileList:
        with open (filename,'r', encoding="ascii", errors  ="surrogateescape") as fin:
            FileinA=(fin.read())
            print (' ')
            #create basename by deleting the file name suffix
            basename=os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
            print (basename)
            #tokenize file
            FileinB=nltk.sent_tokenize(FileinA) 
            word2find = 'retire'
            result = [sentence for sentence in FileinB if word2find in sentence]
        with open (basename+' '+ word2find +'.txt', 'w', encoding="ascii", errors="surrogateescape") as filetowrite:
            filetowrite.write(basename+ ' Retire' + "\n" +"\n")
            for line in result:
                filetowrite.write(line + "\n")
```

Comment: File with a ~ are normally temporary files which are created e.g. by Excel while a file is open. They are hidden so you might not see them in explorer. Try to close Excel while you run your script and see if it still happens.